# Copy and Paste of Files

Tags: linux, copy, paste

How can I copy a selected part of one file (`File 1`) and paste to the second file (`File 2`) after some selected lines via script/commands? The result should be stored in `File 3`.

I have tried with `echo` but `echo` deletes existing content, so i am not getting the desired result.

File 1

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

File 2

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
fffff
.
.
.
```

File3

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

The well-known `cat` program derives its name from *concatenate* and is meant to be used for this:

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

It simply concatenates all files given by name as arguments and prints the result to stdout which you then can redirect into another file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat file1 > file3
```

Followed by:

```
cat file2 >> file3
```

The double `>` allows to append to a file, not deleting existing content.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you need to paste all file1 *before* file2:

```
file1 > file3 && file2>>file3
```

If file1 *after* file2:

```
file2 > file3 && file1>>file3
```

The`>`symbol means you overwrite everything, then `>>` means you add after existing.

If you want to paste something specific, with `echo`, then you should use:

```
echo "Something" > file3
echo " good" >> file3
```

Makes you file with contents *Something good*